# append jquery ajax (json) to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a ajax call that retreives data and its success portion looks like this:

```
$("table.table").append("<tr><td>ID: " + item.ID + "</td><td>Name: " + item.name +" Url:</td><td><a href='https://.......sharepoint.com/" +item.url+ "'><img src='forwarding-icon.png' alt='forward' height='42' width='42'></a>" + "</td></tr>");
```

My html table look like this:

```
<table class="table"></table>
```

I am trying to show  elements like a table:

But instead it's shows like single sentence, like this one: ID: 002 Name: toysrus Url:(icon)

How can I solve this problem and is there any way that I can make items look little bit more modern and useful.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
var uri = 'sharepointmodel.json';  
            function find() {
                var info = $('#KUNDE').val()
                $("#loader").show();
                   $.getJSON(uri)
                    .done(function (data) {                       
                        var item = data.filter(function (obj) {
                            return obj.name === info || obj.ID === info;
                        })[0];
                        if (typeof item ==='undefined'){
                            alert("Ukendt navn eller ID");
                        }
                        else if (typeof item !== 'undefined' || item !== null){                  
             $("table.table").append("<tr><td>ID: " + item.ID + "</td><td>Name: " + item.name +" Url:</td><td><a href='https://........sharepoint.com/" +item.url+ "'><img src='forwarding-icon.png' alt='forward' height='42' width='42'></a>" + "</td></tr>");
                      }                                                
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {                     
                        $('#ERROR').text('Kan ikke oprette forbindelse til serveren! '/* + err*/);}).always(function (){$("#loader").hide();
                    }); 
            }
```

and Html part is:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo">
            <h1></h1>
            <h2></h2>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">SearchBox</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://.com/">.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://.com/support/">Support&Aflastning</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
                <div class="container">   
                <li class="li-myLeagues"> 
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">                      
                                <input type="text" id="KUNDE" placeholder="Search by name or ID." value="" size="60" /> 
                                <div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="loader.gif" /></div>    </div>  
                                <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">              
                                <button id="buton" type="button" class="btn-style" value="search" onclick="find();">Hent</button> 
                                </div> 
                            </li>
                    </div>
                    <div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="loader.gif" /></div>  
                    <section class="section">
            <div class="liper">              
                 <table class="table"></table>         
            <p id="ERROR" />  </p>
            </div>
                </section>
```

Sorry its looks very messy.

Comment: have you inspected it (F12) to see if the data was injected in html code?
the data might have shown correctly, but the table might not have css formatted which resulted in you only saw lines of data.

Comment: You need to state that the content is HTML Table , Have you tried using `.innerHTML` ?  or `.html()` in jquery

Comment: Maybe some of the data that is coming from your ajax call contains HTML tags that could be breaking your `<table>` markup. Can you post the resulting HTML using F12 (developer tools)?

Comment: Can you please share your HTML and json response?

Comment: add border to table and cells, it will show you the things were separated, not in single statement, use bootstrap css for better look and feel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
$("table.table").append("<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>URL</th></tr></thead>");
$("table.table").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>MARC</td><td><a href='https://.......sharepoint.com'><img src='forwarding-icon.png' alt='forward' height='42' width='42'></a></td></tr>");
$("table.table").append("<tr><td>2</td><td>MICHAEL</td><td><a href='https://.......sharepoint.com'><img src='forwarding-icon.png' alt='forward' height='42' width='42'></a></td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 class="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(() => {

            var jsonObject = [{ id: '002', name: 'Google', Icon: 'https://t0.rbxcdn.com/98aeff8137da4af6157fb1c29836d9bc' },
            { id: '002', name: 'Fb', Icon: 'https://t0.rbxcdn.com/875e717ac7ae0df8d133278d0c52f963' },
            { id: '002', name: 'Yahoo', Icon: 'https://t0.rbxcdn.com/875e717ac7ae0df8d133278d0c52f963' }]
            ;

            //Get the external template definition using a jQuery selector
            var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());

            //Create some dummy data
            var data = jsonObject;

            var result = template(data); //Execute the template
            $("table").html(result); //Append the result


        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
   
    <table></table>

    <script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <table>
            <tr> <td><b>ID</b> </td> <td> <b>Name </b>  </td> <td> <b>icon </b> </td> </tr>
            # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
            <tr> <td>   #= data[i].id #</td> <td>  #= data[i].name # </td> <td> <img src="#= data[i].Icon #" width="150px" height="150px"/> </td> </tr>
            # } #
        </table>
    </script>

   




</body>
</html>
```